# InvocationTargetException, from this exception how to extract caused exception with message

Tags: java, exception, java-compiler-api, invocationtargetexception

When run this statement from other Java program.

```
mainMethod.invoke(null,(Object) args);
```

I got this Exception

```
I'm dying!
I'm not dead yet!
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.fourgid.ot.action.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:59)
***Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
at Main$1.checkExit(Main.java:21)
at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:88)
at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:904)
at Main.main(Main.java:30)***
... 5 more
```

i just to show only caused exception that is `SecurityException` with messages and line numbers(above highlighted text) given by JVM.

I am developing an application for compile and execute the program on web.

Thank you!!

Comment: 1) *"Please help me!!"*  Please ask a question & fix that stuck '!' key. *"Thanx!"*  Please spell words like 'thanks' correctly, or better still, leave out such noise. 2) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/). In this case I suggest an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: catch the `InvocationTargetException` and then try [`exception.getCause()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html#getCause%28%29). You might then be able to get more details from the underlying `SecurityException`.